# Using webAPIs in android for login gives FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask

I am very new in using JSON in Android. I have got the webAPI that the base URL is 
Test server. While developing, I am trying to login using email and password from web server database.

A user token is calculated by following formula:
Token = MD5(email + userId); I do not know what is this. What I tried to do is ;

JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;

static JSONObject jObj = null;

static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    System.out.println("url:: "+url );
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    try {

        // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(

        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

        // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
        String line = null;
        // Build the string until null.
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
         // Close the input stream.
        is.close();
         // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
        json = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());

    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object

    try {

        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    //Making HTTP request
    try{
        //check for the request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            //request method to post
            //default HTTPClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();       
        }else if(method == "GET"){
            //request method to GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
      // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}

 }
```

Login.java

```
 public class Login extends Activity {

EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
Button loginBtn;

// Progress Dialog
ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSONParser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// PHP Login Script location
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.sthng.com/ws/?c=profile&func=login";

// JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "Success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "Message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AttemptLogin().execute();

        }

    });
}

// AsyncTask is a seperate thread than the thread that runs the GUI
// Any type of networking should be done with asynctask.
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        int success;

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RegistrationID", ));
            // Log.d("HERE", email);
            // Log.d("HERE2", password);

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting users details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "GET", params);

            Log.d("DEBUG!", "CHECKPOINT");

            // json = json.toString();
            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());

            /*  Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);*/

                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

}

But I am getting error like;

```
04-29 19:03:22.691: D/request!(15060): starting
04-29 19:03:22.736: D/dalvikvm(15060): GC_CONCURRENT freed 222K, 14% free 9575K/11015K, paused 13ms+22ms, total 82ms
04-29 19:03:22.781: W/dalvikvm(15060): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d082a0)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:83)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:519)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at com.example.sthng.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:125)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at com.example.sthng.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:106)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at com.example.sthng.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-29 19:03:22.791: E/AndroidRuntime(15060):    ... 5 more
04-29 19:03:32.686: I/Choreographer(15060): Skipped 589 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060): Activity com.example.sthng.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@427a0298 that was originally added here
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.clipme.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@427a0298 that was originally added here
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:403)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:311)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:554)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at com.example.sthng.Login$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(Login.java:87)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at com.example.sthng.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:61)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
04-29 19:03:33.256: E/WindowManager(15060):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am sure I have done some stupid mistake but please do not take it bad way. I hope I get some hints and solutions for this.

Comment: what is line number 106?

Comment: Please anybody could guide me :S ??

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing UI element `doInBackground()`

```
            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(i);
```

above method on `doInBackground()`. You have to call this method `onPostExecute`.

you are sending email and password two time.

You make url with `https:sthng.com/ws?function=login&email=" + email+ "&password=" + password`

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    "https:sthng.com/ws?function=login&email=" + email
                            + "&password=" + password, "POST", params);
```

or

Now you make below param.

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("androidToken", androidToken));// your token
```

and passing again

```
 DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));// passing again
```

Comment: dude I am not able to login. I comment the intent part at the moment and still getting same errors. Ö)

Comment: @bShah not understand why you are sending email nd password two time

Comment: You are exactly right. I edit my question again and lets see if you get me.

Comment: Dude I have another parameter androidToken.
androidToken: The data required to send notification to Android device, Registration ID. Could you help me how to use this. I am lost.

Comment: Do I need to make another class for androidToken??

Comment: androidToken is your device id ?

Comment: Yes. When I login to the device with email and password it should register the android device. That is RegistrationId of android device.
I am totally lost. Guide me please :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51732/discussion-between-hemant-chand-dungriyal-and-bshah)